# SMS on HTC Desire is not working

Tags: htc-desire, sms, htc-sense

My HTC desire has problems with the texting (sms). Sometimes it doesn't show the thread of my text messages or if it does and I try to click the person to see what they've texted, its a white screen and doesn't do anything. Then sometimes it does go to its original screen and when I click SEND to send a text, it says please wait for a very long time until I click the home button and it goes back to a white screen and its only the texting that is messed up.

Does anyone know how to fix these issues?

Answer (score 1):

Both the default Android messaging app and the HTC Sense app are buggy, as far as I've heard.  Until they get their act together, I recommend trying another SMS app and seeing if it's any better.  [Handcent SMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms) would be a good choice.